# Yammer API call is returning only 50 groups

Tags: yammer

We are using Yammer API Call: https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json to get the yammer groups for our organization. But we are getting only 50 groups for this call. However we are having more than 50. Any thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To get groups beyond the first batch you have to pass a page parameter like this `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?page=5`. Continue paging until you run out of results. Getting only the groups.csv model using the Yammer Data Export is often a faster method, but places additional constraints on the API caller.